# Create warning if program starts to use swap

Tags: python, memory, ram

I'm using python on a somewhat low memory linux system (AWS EC2-micro) with 613 MB.  By default there was no swap so programs would just crash if they hit the memory limit. I've enabled swap, but would still like to see a warning like "Warning: Using swap, performance may decrease" whenever swap is used or whenever the program is using more than a certain amount of swap.

Is there a way to do this within python to create this warning?  Should I be looking outside of python for my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be looking along these lines:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource-usage